# How do you add JavaScript Codes for Social Plug-Ins on a facebook account/page?

Tags: javascript, facebook-iframe, feed, facebook-timeline

FB has converted my Band/Musicains account and page to the timeline and now I don`t have news feed (and about 5 other apps we really need to have.) I really want at least the newsfeed back to socailize but, I don`t understand how/where I am suppose to paste the JavaScript SDK code to,and if that is the actual code I am to use. I`ve asked numerous times on their "help forums" & community forums and made many reports and haven`t recieved any help. This is starting to ruin alot for us and need help! I read through your questions and couldn`t find anything pertaining to not knowing how to use Java Script/HTML on fb. ANY help/suggestions would greatly be appreciated!!!! thanx.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible as Facebook don't provide any ways to embed social plugins in User Profiles or Pages, not with older UI and not with Timeline.

Your Timeline is the new "news feed" (and more).